# nested controllers and actions in url yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a database with tables *teams*, with fields *id* and *name*, and *players* with fields *id*, *team_id* and *name*. I want to create records in the *players* table AFTER I create a record in the *teams* table.

For example, I create a team, go to *edit* - the URL look like this: `/teams/update?id=1` . In the edit section, there is link with text *add player*, which is associated with a controller *Players Controller*. Now the URL of *Players Controller* looks like `/players/create` (in the create section) but I want it to be `/1/players/create`, where 1 corresponds to the *team_id* value. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add two rules in the urlManager setting.

```
'rule' => [
    ...
    "<id:\d+>/<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>"=>"<module>/<controller>/<action>",
    "<id:\d+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>"=>"<controller>/<action>"
]
```

Left side of the equal is pattern, right side of the equal is the route

The id in "< id:\d+ >" means that the arguments to the action like this

```
public function actionCreate($id)
```

So you can change "id" to "teams_id"

"< module:\w+ >" means that match all modules, the other two modes are the same

Read more: [urlmanager-rules-detail](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#$rules-detail)

Comment: thank you for answer. can you please tell me, how exactly should i do it? im new at yii . is it should be like `'teams/<teams_id:\d+>/players/create/' => 'players/create'`